# Bootsrap class not getting rendered in vueJs thorugh v-bind

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, scripting, renderscript

I am trying to render bootstrap class in vueJs though v-bind and it is giving me syntax error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (16:282)

I have used this code to render my bootstrap class.

```
< span class="fa fa-fw field-icon" v-bind:class="{fa-eye:true, fa-eye-slash:false}" 
       style = "font-size: 20px;" @click="switchVisibility">
</span>
```

The rest of the logic is working fine. What syntax error have I made here?

Comment: You can't have `-` unquoted in an object key. Try `{'fa-eye':true, 'fa-eye-slash':false}` instead.

Comment: use as `v-bind:class="{'fa-eye':true, 'fa-eye-slash':false}"`